# Expected number in same position after sorting a list

Tags: probability, sorting

Assume an ordered list $L$ of distinct natural numbers $L_1, L_2, ..., L_n$.

Sort the list. What is the expected number $E(n)$ of elements which stay in the same position? I've been working through an intuition for it, but can't fix it into an inductive proof.

The base case is simple: a list of length 1 has an expected value of 1: it must be in order.

A list of length 2, likewise, has an expected value $E(2)$ of 1: there are two permutations of the elements: one with both in the correct positions and one with none in the correct positions.

With three elements, there are six permutations. One has 3 elements in correct positions, three have 1 element in the correct positions, and two have none. The expected value $E(3)$ is 1, too.

Why is there this regularity?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers For the probability distribution you may refer to this. For the expectation, you just need to note that the total number of elements in correct position (the fixed point) is the sum of $n$ indicators, where each indicator corresponding to a particular position being correct. The probability of being correct is $1/n$ and thus by linearity of expectation the result holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected number is always $1$.

Let $N$ be the number of the $L_i$ which do not move after ordering them. Let $I_i$ be the indicator that $L_i$ does not move, i.e., $I_i=1$ if $L_i$ does not move, and otherwise it is $0$. Then $N=I_1+\cdots+I_n$, and
$$E[N]=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n I_i\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n E[I_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n P(I_i).$$
Now the probability that $L_i$ does not move is the number of permutations of $L_1,\dots,L_n$ in which $L_i$ is in the spot it will be after rearranging (i.e., $(n-1)!$), divided by the total number of permutations of $L_1,\dots,L_n$ (i.e., $n!$). Thus $P(I_i)=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n}$. So, finally, $\sum_{i=1}^n P(I_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}=1$.